# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning always showed up

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to make a discord bot using javascript. My bot is online and my commands are loaded. but whenever i typed a command, this text is showed up and my command didn't do anything

```
(node:4984) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: bot.commands.file is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\bot.js:37:36)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\discord.js\useless bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4984) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4984) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})
const fs = require("fs");
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files)=> {
    if(err) console.log(err);

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
    if (jsfile.lenght <= 0){
        console.log("no commands were found...")
        return;
    }

    jsfile.forEach((f ,i) =>{
        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`)
        console.log(`${f} loaded!`)
        bot.commands.set(props.help, props);
    })
})

bot.on("ready", async ()=> {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online!`);
    bot.user.setActivity("prefix is *", {type: "PLAYING"});
});

bot.on("message", async message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let prefix = config.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
    let cmd = messageArray [0];
    let args = messageArray.slice (1);

    let commandfile = bot.commands.file(cmd.slice(prefix.lenght));
    if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);

})

bot.login(config.token)
```

Comment: It looks like `bot.commands.file` is a promise and does not catch an exception if one occures. You can try `bot.commands.file(cmd.slice(prefix.lenght)).catch(e => console.log(e))`.

Comment: still not working

Comment: are you sure `bot.commands.set(props.help, props);` has been executed before the `message` event?

Comment: hmmmmmm what event? sorry, im just learned this language  like 5 hours ago